# BiConsumer and method reference of one parameter

Tags: java, java-8, this, method-reference, functional-interface

Why is it legal to pass a method reference of one parameter as an argument of expected type `BiConsumer` whose abstract method requires two arguments?

Example:

```
class Experiment {

    private String name;

    public Experiment(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void oneParamMethod(Object o) {
        System.out.println(this.name + " and " + o);
    }

    public <T, S> void executeBiConsumer(BiConsumer<T, S> biCon, T in1, S in2) {
        biCon.accept(in1, in2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // notice that the name is "INSTANCE", but it won't be printed out
        Experiment exp = new Experiment("INSTANCE");

        // executeBiConsumer expects a functional of two params but is given a method 
        // reference of one param. HOW IS THIS LEGAL?
        exp.executeBiConsumer(Experiment::oneParamMethod, new Experiment("PARAM"), 999);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PARAM and 999
```

Let's change the invocation such that the second argument is **not** an instance of `Experiment` as follows:

```
exp.executeBiConsumer(Experiment::oneParamMethod, new String("INVALID"), 999);
```

Now, it won't compile.

---

1. Why does the code compile without complain if the second argument is an `Experiment` instance, and why does it not compile otherwise?
2. Why is it valid to pass a method reference of only one parameter as an argument that expects `BiConsumer`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A method reference referencing an instance method having one argument actually has two arguments - the first argument is implicit - the instance on which the method is executed.

`Experiment::oneParamMethod` is equivalent to `(Experiment e, Object o) -> e.oneParamMethod(o)`.

The `BiConsumer<T, S>` you are passing to `executeBiConsumer` is a `BiConsumer<Experiment,Object>`, which means it must receive an instance of `Experiment` as the first argument of the `accept` method.

Therefore

```
exp.executeBiConsumer(Experiment::oneParamMethod, new Experiment("PARAM"), 999);
```

is valid, but

```
exp.executeBiConsumer(Experiment::oneParamMethod, new String("INVALID"), 999);
```

is not.

Here's a relevant JLS reference ([15.13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1)):

> Second, given a targeted function type with n parameters, a set of potentially applicable methods is identified:
>
> If the method reference expression has the form ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier, the potentially applicable methods are the member methods of the type to search that have an appropriate name (given by Identifier), accessibility, arity (n or n-1), and type argument arity (derived from [TypeArguments]), as specified in §15.12.2.1.
>
> Two different arities, n and n-1, are considered, to account for the possibility that this form refers to either a static method or an instance method.

Your targeted function type - `BiConsumer` - has 2 parameters. Therefore the potentially applicable methods are the member methods of the type to search (`Experiment`) that have the appropriate name (`oneParamMethod`) and arity 2 or 1 (i.e. 1 or 2 arguments). This includes your `public void oneParamMethod(Object o)` method.

Comment: Does this rule extend to instance method with more than 2 parameters? For example, if I have a method reference referencing an instance method of 29 parameters, and then I pass it as an argument that expects a functional interface of 30 parameters, then does the JVM still pass in an implicit argument as the first argument?

Comment: Could you provide reference?

Comment: @NikoGambt yes. Whenever a method reference is referencing a non-static method, the first argument becomes the instance on which the method will be executed.

Comment: @Andronicus added

Answer (score 7):

Adding upon [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58046741/4405757)

There are four kinds of method references

1. Reference to a static method
2. Reference to an instance method of a particular object
3. Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type
4. Reference to a constructor

The one you are using belongs to the third category. We can see this better if we substitute the method reference using lambda.

What you are doing is

```
BiConsumer<Experiment, Integer> biCon = (experiment, someInt) -> 
            experiment.oneParamMethod(someInt)
```

The first argument becomes the `object` on which the `oneParamMethod` is called. The method reference equivalent of the above is what you were using - `Experiment::oneParamMethod`.

---

If you were to convert `oneParamMethod` static, you would get an error as `Class::staticMethod`'s lambda form would be to pass the arguments as it is to the static method.

It would look like

```
BiConsumer<Experiment, Integer> biCon = (experiment, someInt) -> 
        Experiment.oneParamMethod(experiment, someInt)
```

and you don't have a `oneParamMethod` method taking two parameters.

References:

[Oracle Method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

[Method References](https://javadevcentral.com/java-method-references)

---

> Ah, I have a problem with the description of the third kind.

This is not as complex as it sounds. We use `Class::instanceMethod` most of the time when we use `stream..filter..map`. Let us say, we want to filter `Person` object whose age is more than 18.

```
persons.stream()
       .filter(person -> person.getAge() > 18)
       .map(person -> person.getName()) //Get only name
       ...
```

Here, `person -> person.getName()` can be written as `Person::getName`. This is the same case as 3rd category. The first *implict* argument is the **arbitrary object of a particular type** and `getName` is the **instance method**.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah, I have a problem with the description of the third kind. To me, the description is certainly not helpful. The example given using an array and `Arrays.sort()` also doesn't exactly pinpoint what the third kind actually is.

Comment: See edit. Hope it answers your question

Comment: Thank you. Now I get it. It's certainly baffling that the tutorial doesn't explain that the "arbitrary object" is passed in as an *implicit* first argument. Who could have guessed it just by reading the wording in the tutorial?